# Android app using Facebook library can't find com_facebook_android.apk

Tags: android, facebook

*(I hope this is readable, I'm trying to format my code blocks, but don't see a preview)*

I’m following the instructions for getting started with facebook apps on Android (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android ).  I’ve got the facebook sdk installed via git and I’ve got that imported into eclipse as an android library via File->Import in Eclipse.  I’ve got Facebook installed on my emulator (a 2.2 target if it matters) and was able to make a test post to my wall with it.  The activity in my HelloWorld App is essentially word for word the example on the linked page above.

Before the step where I add the fb SSO code, I’ve essentially got hello world with the following line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

This works.

When the fb code is in, I still expect to see that eventually, but I also expect to see facebook’s authorization dialog before my hello world line.  If I add a permission, such as email and read_stream and then re-run the app, I expect to see the dialog requesting that I grant or reject these permissions.  In fact, I see the same thing as in the plain Jane, Hello World case.

Something odd that comes up when I run my app is the following error in the console:

```
[2011-09-06 07:30:21 - HelloWorld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-09-06 07:30:53 - HelloWorld] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-09-06 07:30:53 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-09-06 07:30:54 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
[2011-09-06 07:31:35 - HelloWorld] Success!
[2011-09-06 07:31:35 - Facebook] Could not find com_facebook_android.apk!
[2011-09-06 07:31:35 - HelloWorld] Starting activity com.HelloWorld.client.HelloWorldActivity on device emulator-5554
[2011-09-06 07:31:37 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.HelloWorld.client/.HelloWorldActivity }
```

It appears that after my app is on the emulator, but before it starts its activity, it goes looking for com_facebook_android.apk  and can’t find it.  I know from installing Facebook on the emulator that it is in fact Facebook.apk, not com_facebook_android.apk.

So my questions are:

1. If it correct that my app is looking for com_facebook_android.apk? 
   Should it instead be looking for Facebook.apk?
2. com_facebook_android.apk looks a lot like it is supposed to be an
   app installed by the android library app; especially because it
   carries the name, com_facebook_android.  com_facebook_android is a
   library and can’t be run.  Do I need to uncheck the library and run
   it so that it is installed?  This would seem a bit hackish and I
   expect that my app should have a single .apk at the end.  I tried
   renaming it via Eclipse’s refactoring tool to “Facebook”.  This had
   no discernable effect other than to change my failure message to 
   "Could not find Facebook.apk"; and I'd expect that to be found in 
   any case as there is in fact an apk by that name installed.

Does anyone have any words of wisdom about how to resolve this error?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is correct it looks for com_facebook_android.apk
most likely it is a project misconfiguration issue in eclipse

check out this thread:
[I get a "could not find com_facebook_android.apk error" when I run my Android project](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7258394/i-get-a-could-not-find-com-facebook-android-apk-error-when-i-run-my-android-pro/7265972#7265972)